# Print size of all tables created in given year

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin

I have a database full of tables. 
I'm using pgAdmin to access it. 
One table's name is `timecycle` and the others are called `event_run_x` where 'x' is a number for each different table.

**I would like to list all the tables with it's size but those who where created only on 2018.**

So far I was able to list all the databases with it's size with:

```
SELECT relname AS table_name, pg_size_pretty(table_size) AS size, table_size
    FROM (
        SELECT pg_catalog.pg_namespace.nspname AS schema_name, relname, pg_relation_size(pg_catalog.pg_class.oid) AS table_size
        FROM pg_catalog.pg_class JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace ON relnamespace = pg_catalog.pg_namespace.oid
    ) t
    WHERE schema_name NOT LIKE 'pg_%';
```

Each table `event_run_x` has many elements with different id's. From the table `timecycle` I have the same id's and a column named `date`. I am able to get all the id's from the year 2018 with:

```
SELECT * FROM timecycle WHERE extract(year from date) = 2018
```

Now **what I would need is to change the first code to list only the tables that has an id that is listed in the last query. (from timecycle year 2018)**

id's from `event_run_x` does not repeat within another `event_run_y` (x != y ofc). **Each `event_run_x` id is supposed to have the same year**. So if there is an id from say `event_run_8` in the timecycle query, then all the id's from `event_run_8` will be in said query and vice versa.

---

Example:

```
Event_run_1:
id  |
----|
1   |
2   |
3   |
4   |
-----
Event_run_2:
id  |
----|
5   |
6   |
7   |
----|

timecycle:
id  | date
-----------
1   | 2018-01-01 00:00:00
2   | 2018-01-01 00:00:00
2   | 2018-01-01 00:00:00
3   | 2018-01-01 00:00:00
4   | 2018-01-01 00:00:00
5   | 2017-01-01 00:00:00
6   | 2017-01-01 00:00:00
7   | 2017-01-01 00:00:00
--------------------------
```

I am currently getting:

```
table_name    | size     | table_size
--------------------------------------
"event_run_1" | "23 MB"  | "24272896"
"event_run_1" | "167 MB" | "175046656"
```

What I want is event_run_1 to be listed but not event_run_2.

---

PS: If I am over-complicating things and one can do it without sql queries or whatever it can also be a solution. I think no other options where possible because of:  [PostgreSQL: Table creation time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577168/postgresql-table-creation-time)

---

I tried the answer from [Automatically Drop Tables and Indexes Older than 90 Days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18849756/automatically-drop-tables-and-indexes-older-than-90-days/18852752#18852752) that I got from this answer [PostgreSQL: Creation date of a table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3093/postgresql-creation-date-of-a-table) but got:

```
ERROR: must be superuser to get directory listings 
SQL state: 42501
```

Comment: I don't get it. What are the "elements" a table has and whose ids you find in `timecycle`? Rows?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe, `timecycle` has only 2 columns. Id and date. And for the sake of clarity, `event_run_x` has only one column that is id. I'll add an example in the intent to clarify right now.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you leverage the sys tables for this.   You can easily get the create_date of a table out of sys.tables.

```
Select * from sys.tables where create_date between '1/1/2018' and '12/31/2018'
```

You can join that output to whatever query you prefer that has the table sizes display the data the way you want.   The only caveat to something like this would be if you are dealing with a database that has established processes that drop and create tables.  This is not unheard of and could show you some results you don't like.   You would have to further filter for any known tables that fall into that scenario.

All in all this shouldn't be very hard to put together.

Comment: With that exact query I'm getting: `ERROR:  relation "sys.tables" does not exist`. I tried googling it but I did't find why I get the error...

Comment: This works on MSSQL, are your running Oracle or MySQL?

Comment: The server is using PostgreSQL and I access it via pgAdmin.