# How to know which query created a certain table in the schema

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

We have a table in the schema which was created by a certain user. How can I know what query the user executed to create that table (user is no longer with the company)? Basically trying to find out which underlying tables were used to create said user created table.

Apologies about the briefness, let me know what I can add to explain better.

Comment: Which SQL server?

Comment: This is Redshift.

Comment: It looks like Redshift has some auditing capabilities but the best I could find was this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36847240/is-there-any-way-to-find-table-creation-date-in-redshift