# Dropping tables in a particular schema after X number of days from table creation date

Tags: amazon-redshift, ddl

I have a schema specific for temporary tables in redshift. Eventually, as creation of a lot of tables takes a lot of space, I would like to know the following:

- Is there a way to automate deletion of tables in that schema after X days(lets say 30 days) after the table's creation date?
- Any articles on the above question I can refer to?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could start on [Is there any way to find table creation date in redshift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36847240/is-there-any-way-to-find-table-creation-date-in-redshift)
You can first collect the output to a temporary table and then run something that `DROP`s tables that have age over your threshold or you can do it in one step.