Need to find how redshift table got loaded
I have a Redshift table in production.

db.table_name

I need to find how this table got loaded. Is there any system table present by which i can see the dependency. Basically i want to check the what source table used in here.
As of now i perform right click on the table and checked the dependency option but it is not helping me much.
I am new to Redshift. Can someone one help me.

This Q&A has some good info - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36847240/is-there-any-way-to-find-table-creation-date-in-redshift  In general Redshift doesn't keep log tables more than a few days so if this is recent you can see the code that created it in the DDL and query logs.  If not you will looking in pg_class_info for creation time.
