# How to know the date of modification of an SP?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.4, event-triggers

Is it possible to know the date of modification and / or creation of an SP in PostgreSQL 9.4?

I need to identify them to upload them next Deploy.-

Comment: SP is user defined function?..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577168/postgresql-table-creation-time

Comment: @VaoTsun - 2577168 is obsolete - now PostgreSQL has event triggers and this issue can be solved well by system functions.

Comment: @PavelStehule yes, completely agree, btw - why nobody adds this fix to the 2577168? I think absence of `last_ddl` in postgres was a holy war before event triggers

Comment: @VaoTsun - partially true, it was possible with some C extensions, but there was not a clean simply solution. The philosophy of PostgreSQL: "do nothing if you can't to do correctly". It has advantages disadvantages.

Comment: Thank you all for the answers!!!

Answer (score 3):

PostgreSQL has not this functionality. You can create own table and update it from [event triggers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/event-triggers.html).

```
create table updates(proc regprocedure primary key, t timestamp);

create or replace function event_trigger_for_ddl_command_end()
returns event_trigger as $$
declare obj record;
begin
  for obj in select * from pg_event_trigger_ddl_commands()
  loop
    if obj.classid = 'pg_proc'::regclass then
      insert into updates values(obj.objid, current_timestamp)
          on conflict (proc) do update set t = current_timestamp
                             where updates.proc = excluded.proc;
    end if;
  end loop;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;

create event trigger trigger_for_ddl_command_end
  on ddl_command_end
  execute procedure event_trigger_for_ddl_command_end();

create or replace function fx(a int) returns int as $$ select 1 $$ language sql;

postgres=# select * from updates ;
+-------------+----------------------------+
|    proc     |             t              |
+-------------+----------------------------+
| fx(integer) | 2017-11-22 14:21:11.367036 |
+-------------+----------------------------+
(1 row)

-- alternative code without INSERT ON CONFLICT
create or replace function event_trigger_for_ddl_command_end()
returns event_trigger as $$
declare obj record;
begin
  for obj in select * from pg_event_trigger_ddl_commands()
  loop
    if obj.classid = 'pg_proc'::regclass then
      begin
        update updates set t = current_timestamp
           where proc = obj.objid;
        if not found then
          begin
            insert into updates values(obj.objid, current_timestamp);
          exception when unique_violation then
            update updates set t = current_timestamp
               where proc = obj.objid;
          end;
        end if;
    end if;
  end loop;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Comment: When creating the SP event_trigger_for_ddl_command_end() I get the following:

ERROR:  error de sintaxis en o cerca de «on»
LINE 8:           on conflict (proc) do update set t = current_times...

Comment: @Max What is a version of your postgres?

Comment: I have PostgreSQL 9.4

Comment: @Max hmm 9.4. doesn't support `INSERT ON CONFLICT`.