# is there any way to get creation time of PostgreSQL objects

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I tried to looking into pg_class and pg_attribute as well, but no luck. There are some of the functions in my DB that is deployed some time back. And I want to know when those functions are created. It will help me to audit the deployments scripts.

Comment: Related ? : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577168/postgresql-table-creation-time

Comment: @Jaisus I got some idea that, PostgreSQL doesn't store this information anywhere. But if we want to record this information from now onward we can. But I am worry about the function which is deployed long time back.