# PostgreSQL database default location on Linux

Tags: linux, postgresql

What is the default directory where PostgreSQL will keep all databases on Linux?

Comment: Another thread where the same questions was discussed.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137060/where-does-postgresql-store-the-database

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where does PostgreSQL store the database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137060/where-does-postgresql-store-the-database)

Answer (score 167, accepted):

The "*directory where postgresql will keep all databases*" (and configuration) is called "data directory" and corresponds to what PostgreSQL calls (a little confusingly) a "[database cluster](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/creating-cluster.html)", which is not related to distributed computing, it just means a group of databases and related objects managed by a PostgreSQL server.

The location of the data directory depends on the distribution. If you install from source, the default is `/usr/local/pgsql/data`:

> In file system terms, a database
> cluster will be a single directory
> under which all data will be stored.
> We call this the data directory or
> data area. It is completely up to you
> where you choose to store your data.
> There is no default, although
> locations such as
> /usr/local/pgsql/data or
> /var/lib/pgsql/data are popular.
> ([ref](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/creating-cluster.html))

Besides, an instance of a running PostgreSQL server is associated to one cluster; the location of its data directory can be passed to the server daemon ("[postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-postgres.html)") in the `-D` command line option, or by the `PGDATA` environment variable (usually in the scope of the running user, typically `postgres`). You can usually see the running server with something like this:

```
[root@server1 ~]# ps auxw |  grep postgres | grep -- -D
postgres  1535  0.0  0.1  39768  1584 ?        S    May17   0:23 /usr/local/pgsql/bin/postgres -D /usr/local/pgsql/data
```

Note that it is possible, though not very frequent, to run two instances of the same PostgreSQL server (same binaries, different processes) that serve different "clusters" (data directories). Of course, each instance would listen on its own TCP/IP port.

Comment: I can see the current data directory, but I see many other folders and files. Does psql "save" the database in many files or is there only one inside this data directory that is the DB? because I was thinking in something like the DB file on mysql or sql server for example...

Comment: This works up to CentOS 7, but not CentOS 8.  Not sure about other distributions.  There is another answer with the new command for CentOS 8.  See my comment.

Comment: @MacGyver Thanks for pointing that out. Could you provide the link to that comment of yours?

Comment: @leonbloy /var/lib/pgsql/data/ is the path for CentOS 8.  But you provided the way to obtain it by running the "ps auxw | grep postres | grep -- -D".

Answer (score 97):

```
/var/lib/postgresql/[version]/data/
```

At least in Gentoo Linux and Ubuntu 14.04 by default.

You can find `postgresql.conf` and look at param `data_directory`. If it is commented then database directory is the same as this config file directory.

Comment: It will be depending on the distribution, they all do it slightly differently. If you can connect to the system, using "SHOW data_directory" is probably the easiest way.

Comment: @MagnusHagander it is an answer, y do not you make this comment an answer. It worked well for me.

Comment: in Gnome I see the same here `/var/lib/8.1/postgresql`

Comment: For me its '/var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main'

Comment: for Centos 7, postgres 9.3 path `/var/lib/pgsql/9.3`

Comment: @MagnusHagander what do you mean `if you can connect to the system`? What's the system?

Comment: I found this Answer to be true in Docker Desktop 4.22.

Answer (score 57):

Connect to a database and execute the command:

```
SHOW data_directory;
```

More information:

[https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-show.html](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-show.html)
[https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-file-locations.html](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/runtime-config-file-locations.html)

Answer (score 19):

Default in Debian 8.1 and PostgreSQL 9.4 after the installation with the package manager *apt-get*

```
ps auxw |  grep postgres | grep -- -D
postgres 17340  0.0  0.5 226700 21756 ?        S    09:50   0:00 /usr/lib/postgresql/9.4/bin/postgres -D /var/lib/postgresql/9.4/main -c config_file=/etc/postgresql/9.4/main/postgresql.conf
```

so apparently `/var/lib/postgresql/9.4/main`.

Answer (score 15):

On Centos 6.5/PostgreSQL 9.3:

Change the value of `"PGDATA=/var/lib/pgsql/data"` to whatever location you want in the initial script file `/etc/init.d/postgresql`.

Remember to  `chmod 700`  and `chown postgres:postgres` to the new location and you're the boss.

Answer (score 5):

The command `pg_lsclusters` (at least under Linux / Ubuntu) can be used to list the existing clusters and with it also the data directory:

```
Ver Cluster Port Status Owner    Data directory               Log file
9.5 main    5433 down   postgres /var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.5-main.log
10  main    5432 down   postgres /var/lib/postgresql/10/main  /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-10-main.log
```

Answer (score 4):

Below query will help to find postgres configuration file.

```
postgres=# SHOW config_file;
             config_file
-------------------------------------
 /var/lib/pgsql/data/postgresql.conf
(1 row)

[root@node1 usr]# cd /var/lib/pgsql/data/
[root@node1 data]# ls -lrth
total 48K
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres    4 Nov 25 13:58 PG_VERSION
drwx------ 2 postgres postgres    6 Nov 25 13:58 pg_twophase
drwx------ 2 postgres postgres    6 Nov 25 13:58 pg_tblspc
drwx------ 2 postgres postgres    6 Nov 25 13:58 pg_snapshots
drwx------ 2 postgres postgres    6 Nov 25 13:58 pg_serial
drwx------ 4 postgres postgres   36 Nov 25 13:58 pg_multixact
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres  20K Nov 25 13:58 postgresql.conf
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres 1.6K Nov 25 13:58 pg_ident.conf
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres 4.2K Nov 25 13:58 pg_hba.conf
drwx------ 3 postgres postgres   60 Nov 25 13:58 pg_xlog
drwx------ 2 postgres postgres   18 Nov 25 13:58 pg_subtrans
drwx------ 2 postgres postgres   18 Nov 25 13:58 pg_clog
drwx------ 5 postgres postgres   41 Nov 25 13:58 base
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres   92 Nov 25 14:00 postmaster.pid
drwx------ 2 postgres postgres   18 Nov 25 14:00 pg_notify
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres   57 Nov 25 14:00 postmaster.opts
drwx------ 2 postgres postgres   32 Nov 25 14:00 pg_log
drwx------ 2 postgres postgres 4.0K Nov 25 14:00 global
drwx------ 2 postgres postgres   25 Nov 25 14:20 pg_stat_tmp
```

Answer (score 3):

I think best method is to query `pg_setting` view:

```
 select s.name, s.setting, s.short_desc from pg_settings s where s.name='data_directory';
```

Output:

```
      name      |        setting         |            short_desc
----------------+------------------------+-----------------------------------
 data_directory | /var/lib/pgsql/10/data | Sets the server's data directory.
(1 row)
```