# PostgreSQL data file location

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I am using PostgreSQL on Mac, I have created several databases using command line. I am looking into /Library/PostgreSQL/9.2/data and I can not see any .dat file. Am I looking into the wrong place for data files?

I have used the following command: 
ps auxw |  grep postgres | grep -- -D
as mentioned [PostgreSQL database default location on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004523/postgresql-database-default-location-on-linux) and it gives me the /Library/PostgreSQL/9.2/data directory.

Any ideas?

Comment: `select setting from pg_settings where name = 'data_directory'` shows you the real path of the data directory (you must be connect to PostgreSQL as a superuser)

Comment: Do not know about Mac. If this can help, in my Linux box they are located under /var/lib/pgsql/data/. Anyway, the files are only visible for the user postgresql. May be your files are there but hidden for your current user.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
select setting from pg_settings where name = 'data_directory'
```

and

```
ps auxw | grep postgres | grep -- -D
```

both generate the same result. The first one through postgresql, second one command line. Thanks to @a_horse_with_no_name

Answer (score 3):

PostgreSQL lets you store data in relatively arbitrary locations in the filesystem. The default location, which you can get with `show data_directory`, [isn't the whole story](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8237512/562459).