# Difference between /usr/lib/ and /usr/local/ in installation of PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I am reading this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3006482/54964) and the manual of PostgreSQL 9.4.
I run

```
ps auxw |  grep postgres | grep -- -D
```

but get

```
postgres 17340  0.0  0.5 226700 21756 ?        S    09:50   0:00 /usr/lib/postgresql/9.4/bin/postgres -D /var/lib/postgresql/9.4/main -c config_file=/etc/postgresql/9.4/main/postgresql.conf
```

but the default installation location should be `/usr/local/pgsql/` according to the manual at *file:///usr/share/doc/postgresql-doc-9.4/html/install-short.html*.

It may be possible that the database was `initdb` in the `/usr/lib/` directory.

How can you change the installation location of PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thread you're reading says that the installation directory is `/usr/local/pgsql` when you install from source, so I suppose this is what you do as well. To change the directory that `make install` uses for installation, you need to specify the `--prefix` argument to `configure`:

```
./configure --prefix=/path/to/install
make
sudo make install
```

PS: in case you don't install from source, refer to the documentation which comes with your package manager.