# Where is PostgreSQL database file stored? (Django Project)

Tags: django, postgresql, postgresql-9.2, django-database

I am working on a Django project and have started to used Postgres (as opposed to sqlite3), however, I am unsure where the database file is stored. I am on a Mac OS X Mavericks, and am starting my server using [Postgress.app](http://postgresapp.com/). I also have pgAdmin3 installed. I would like to move my database from where it is currently stored and into my Django filder so that i can upload it when I am ready to deploy my project, this way i can have the tables i have already written to my database. Does anyone know where the database files for postgres are store on Mac OS and how I can copy it to my project folder? Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137060/where-does-postgresql-store-the-database

Comment: I suggest you to do a backup/restore of your database, and not even think about copy/past server internal files (even if it can be possible in your case)