# Where is PostgreSQL server installed in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, postgresql, windows-8.1

I want to share my PostgreSQL server with another machine but I cannot find where the database server is installed.

Can anyone tell me where the server is installed under Windows 8.1?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where does PostgreSQL store the database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137060/where-does-postgresql-store-the-database)

Answer (score 1):

By default the data directory for PostgresDB in Windows is `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\<your-version>\data`

However you could go and export the databases via `pg_dump` or `pgAdmin` and restore them on the other machine.

Answer (score -1):

If it is installed as services, just look to services and see "path to executable".

You will find something like:

```
"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\bin\pg_ctl.exe" runservice -N "postgresql-x64-9.3" -D "O:/pgdata_9.3" -w
```

Where you have both executable path and datadir path (the one on -D parameter).