# postgres flask db doesnt appear in main project directory pg admin III, but appears to be working

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

So I built a postgres models.py and tried to create the below test data, all of which worked with sqlite.

```
basedir = os.getcwd()

app = Flask(__name__)

#...omitted for brevity

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

app.config['ENV_DB_CONNECTION_DSN'] = 'postgres:///Ocean.db'

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

db.create_all()

#testing starts below this

camelot = Entity(level='Province', name='Camelot',iso_code='CAM')

db.session.add(camelot)

lit = Literal_data(ent_id=1, year=2012, value=2, display_name = 'swallow count', meta_id=1)

db.session.add(lit)

swallow = Meta_indicator_data(p_name = 'swallow count',family = 'animal life',num_type = 'interger',provider = 'camelot bird comission',p_description = 'swallows. duh.')

db.session.add(swallow)

db.session.commit()
```

the above works fine, i can even query the db with db.engine.execute('select * from ent')

Only problem is I cant find the db file anywhere, including psgadmin III!

any ideas on how to print the db file name? can the above run with no errors without a db file??

Comment: Is it perhaps at the root of your filesystem, i.e. `/`?

Comment: Good thinking, but no

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where does PostgreSQL store the database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137060/where-does-postgresql-store-the-database)

Comment: I don't think so, I can see a directory with a bunch folders named for OIDs, but I cant tell what they correspond to. I have added and deleted test datbases before. Is there a way to read OIDs?

Comment: So apparently when I am commiting the data, the engine redefaults to sql lite


`>>> db
<SQLAlchemy engine='sqlite://'>
`
help??

Comment: when I chang the config to
`app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql:///uiop:password@localhost:5432/Ocean.db'`

i get

`sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) fe_sendauth: no password supplied`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically my config just sucked I think, been a while since I was dealing with this. the current code reads

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
try:
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = os.environ['DATABASE_URL']
except KeyError:
    raise Exception('I dont see a database connection in the Database URL system variablbe - see the read me on setting this up')
```

Where:

```
database_url = postgresql://$user:$password@localhost:5432/$databasename
```

Comment: Thanks Saurav! looks much better