# default Postgres is 14, database files are at v12

Tags: postgresql, homebrew

My default Postgres (installed via brew) is at v14, and I can't start it because the files are at version 12:

`DETAIL:  The data directory was initialized by PostgreSQL version 12, which is not compatible with this version 14.0.`

I can't upgrade the files:

```
==> Moving postgresql data back from /usr/local/var/postgres.old to /usr/local/var/postgres...
Error: Failure while executing; `/usr/local/opt/postgresql/bin/initdb --lc-collate=C --lc-ctype=C --lc-messages=C --lc-monetary=C --lc-numeric=C --lc-time=C -E\ UTF8 /usr/local/var/postgres` exited with 1.
```

There is also this error when I do brew services:

`postgresql error /usr/local/opt/postgresql/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist`

I have version @12 installed but when I open it I can't see the databases in my default install.

What is the best path forward to resolve this?

Comment: Did you tried doing pgdump_all on the version 12 and later restore to version 14?

Comment: @JoseCabreraZuniga - no will pgdump_all work even though my default install is not running?

Comment: you might need to config your postgres 12 to use the folder where the DB files are located and try again. Out of that... I am out of options.

Comment: @JoseCabreraZuniga do you know what path I put in on OSX?  Do I just put in /usr/local/var/postgres ?

Comment: Hope this link can help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137060/where-does-postgresql-store-the-database

Comment: Thanks for your assistance, I was able to get it going by copying the Postgres directory to Postgres@12.

Answer (score 1):

On your postgres 12 set the folder where the data you need (or a copy of this folder) as the working folder for postgres 12. Do pgdump on this version and then pg_restore on postgres 14.

Use the next link to identify the working folder:

[Where does PostgreSQL store the database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137060/where-does-postgresql-store-the-database)