# C# NpgSQL ORDER BY not working correctly (Bit.io)

Tags: c#, sql, npgsql

I have several other SQL commands using NpgSQL all working correctly. Commands like INSERT INTO and DELETE FROM.

However, within the same project, and the same code, I can not get a database to order itself using ORDER BY. If I run the command within Bit.io, it works. Once I copy and paste the command into my C# project, it does not have the correct behavior.

```
using var con = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionString);
con.Open();
String sql = "SELECT * FROM databaseName ORDER BY columnName";
NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand(sql, con);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

It is supposed to order columnName in databaseName alphabetically, but what happens is the database is ordered seemingly in an arbitrary way each time that has no relation to the colunn.

If I run ONLY the command `SELECT * FROM databaseName`, the same behavior occurs.

The code does not have compilation or runtime errors.

Comment: _"It is supposed to order columnName in databaseName alphabetically"_ - no, it does not. `ORDER BY` orders the query result set, not the datastore itself.

Comment: I do not understand. When the command is run within the query editor on bit.io, it does in fact sort the table. Am I missing a step?

Comment: You mean query results tab? =) That is not a database that is query results.

Comment: I don't know. I am just trying to sort the database, the "Query editor" in bit.io allows me to input SQL commands to run against the database. When I run SQL in there or in my C# project, the results are identical, EXCEPT for ORDER BY, which is what I am having the issue with. The ORDER BY within Bit.io's query editor does update the database, but not when executed from my C# project. I do not know why

Comment: For your own sake, find a good SQL or tutorial and learn the basics about how things work. If you don't, you're going to get very frustrated and annoyed for a very long period of time.

Answer (score 2):

As written in the comments - `ORDER BY` does not sort the stored data itself, it sorts the data returned by query. Your query actually returns data so you can process it on the application side:

```cs
using var con = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionString);
con.Open();
String sql = "SELECT * FROM databaseName ORDER BY columnName";
using NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand(sql, con);
using var reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync();
while (await reader.ReadAsync())
{
    Console.WriteLine(reader.GetString(0));
}
```

Read more:

- [Npgsql Basic Usage](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/basic-usage.html#commands)
- [Introduction To SQL And SQL Commands](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/introduction-to-sql-and-sql-commands/)
- [Where does PostgreSQL store the database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137060/where-does-postgresql-store-the-database)
- [Database Physical Storage](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/storage.html)

Comment: Ok, what I need to do is order the database itself, per the instructions given to me. Is there a step I need to do to make that happen?

Comment: @Otteko  _"what I need to do is order the database itself"_ - but why? It seems that either you are missing something in understanding how databases usually work or it is an [x-y problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Or both.

Comment: @Otteko databases like PostgreSQL store data in files. Usually the way of how data is stored and ordered is an implementation detail which should not be a concern of application developer. And I'm not sure that all existing database which store data in files have some tools to affect that ordering.